# Need javascript/Form to open in new tab

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript and a form that allows users to enter search terms and then loads the appropriate page with search results from a sharepoint site...only problem being that it loads the results on that browser tab and I need it to (*try*) open on a new tab.

I have tried working target = "_blank" into the code but cant seem to get it to work. I have also seen examples using window.open but cant figure out how to incorperate this into my code...Any help would be appreciated

Code is

```js
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
 // Search for the terms when the Search button is clicked

 function customSearch(type,site,scope) {

  var searchUrl = "*website link will be here*"
  var searchTerm = "&k=" + document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
  var listParams = "&cs=This%20" + type + "&u=" + scope;
  document.location.href = searchUrl + searchTerm + listParams;

 }

 // Initiate the customSearch function when the Enter key is pressed

 function searchKeyPress(e) {
  // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
  if (window.event) { e = window.event; }
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
   document.getElementById('searchButton').click();
  }
 }
// ]]></script>
<input id="searchBox" onkeypress="javascript:searchKeyPress(event);" type="text" name="searchBox" placeholder="Search SharePoint" />
<input id="searchButton" onclick="javascript:customSearch ( 'List', 'http://server/site', '*website link will be here*' )";" type="button" name="searchButton" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: `window.open()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open instead of `document.location.href` - Also, you can drop `javascript:` from the `onclick` and `onkeypress` event, as they are just used as a replacement URL scheme in `href` attributes.

Comment: And if you wanted to get super fancy, you can use the fancybox.js library to have the page load elegantly on top of your page, that way you can avoid pop blockers and such. http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/DRvyq/

Comment: @somethinghere Thanks alot!

Comment: @spazum89 Glad to help! Good luck :)